# C program - different behaviour on different machines. Memory allocation problem?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, ubuntu, memory-management

I have a C program giving different results when run on two machines.

On the first machine (Linux Ubuntu, gcc compiler v 4.4.3, 64bit, 4GB memory) it seems to work fine and gives reasonable results (actually this is the machine on which it has been mainly developed).

On the second machine (Mac OSX 10.5.8, gcc compiler v 4.4.5, 32bit, 2GB memory) the results appear to be nonsense.

In particular, there is an array A filled in during a FOR cycle in which each term A[i] depends on A[i-1]. I have found out that after about 4000 steps my machine starts to forget the A[i-1] values and then calculates nonsense.

Even more bizarre to me, the problem disappears if in the initial list of variable declaration of the function I add another fictitious array, which I don't even use in the program.

That is, a code with a header like

```
...
double X[n_max];           
double Y[n_max]; 
double A[n_max]; 
...
```

works, while

```
...
double X[n_max];           
// double Y[n_max]; 
double A[n_max];
```

does not.

I guess there is some sort of problem in memory allocation, and that when I allocate memory for the fictitious array Y the mess is simply moved elsewhere.

I don't understand neither why my Mac seems to have no problems in overwriting data it is supposed to remember, nor why the same program is working on the Linux machine.

I hope that the problem is clear, any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Would you show the actual code?

Comment: run it with valgrind (`apt-get install valgrind gdb`; `sudo -E valgrind --db-attachb=yes ./test`)

Comment: What is n_max? Don't you overflow the limits of A?

Comment: Set all elements of Y to a known value, run your program, then check whether Y has been changed.

Comment: The actual code is quite long and I didn't write it myself, so I am not sure of which part is actually causing the problem and I don't know what would be relevant to show.

Comment: I have tried to run it with valgrind, initially I got 6 errors for uninitialized variables ("Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value"), I've fixed them but the overall result has not changed.
What is left is: "still reachable: 21,057 bytes in 7 blocks" and "suppressed: 340 bytes in 8 blocks"

From the valgrind help I understand that the 'still reachable' parts should not be a problem. I don't see any other information in the log about the 'suppressed' parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is obvious that one of the X[] or A[] arrays is being indexed out of bounds. Just as a test replace all array indices by unsigned or size_t, recompile and run under a debugger. The program will probably segfault.

Answer (score 2):

First - you certainly have a bug in your program, and turning up the level of compiler warnings, or running with valgrind may help find it.

The memory layout is naturally different, because of different compilers and CPU architecture, my first guess would be that the issue is related to 64bit vs 32bit architecture (impacting pointer sizes, memory alignement, etc.).

Comment: As I wrote also in a comment above, after fixing a couple of variables which were not initialized I get 0 errors with valgrind. In the end there are just 'still reachable' and 'suppressed' parts, nothing lost, and I don't know if this is relevant or not.


Which kind of warning should I try to turn on in the compiler?